# Complex Analysis: Laurent Series: Analyticity of a function except at isolated singularities

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

I'm learning about Laurent Series and I'm having trouble with a certain part of the class notes.

The Laurent Series for a function $f(z)$ around a point $z_0$ is defined as

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n$$

Where

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z')dz'}{(z' - z_0)}$$

I understand how this result is arrived at. However I have some questions:

---

I'm a little unnerved by the idea of summing from negative infinity to positive infinity. I get how you do that for integrals, but this is a discrete sum. In particular, can I rearrange it like this?

$$f(z) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \big(a_n(z-z_0)^n + \frac{a_{-n}}{(z' - z_0)^n}\big)$$

I vaguely remember that rearranging the order of the terms in an infinite sum is a delicate business, and I want to know if this is allowed?

---

The text defines what the different kinds of poles and singularities mean, in terms of how many of the negative coefficients are zero. e.g. All $a_{-n} = 0$ from $n=-\infty$ to $n=-k$ means the pole is of order $k$. So far, so good. Next it says something I find quite cryptic:

> It follows from these that poles are isolated singularities: $f(z)$ is only non-analytic at and immediately around $z_0$. This is easily proved, by **multiplying through by $(z-z_0)^n$** [emphasis mine], which produces a series without negative powers, and thus represents an analytic function. If the function $(z-z_0)^n f(z)$ is analytic, $f(z)$ must be analytic except at $z = z_0$.

By the look of it, the bolded part seems to mean:

$$f(z)(z-z_0)^n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^{2n}$$

If the previous rearranging is allowed, then it might mean:

$$f(z)(z-z_0)^n = a_0(z-z_0)^n + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \big(a_n(z-z_0)^{2n} + a_{-n}\big)$$

Both of which I think are nonsense. You can't multiply the whole equation by something that depends on a sum's index. The LHS now has an $n$ in it, which doesn't make any sense.

How am I meant to interpret "multiplying through by $(z-z_0)^n$", and how *exactly* does it get rid of the negative powers?

Comment: There is probably a typo in the text, i.e. that one should multiply by $(z-z_0)^k$.

Comment: How does that produce a series without any negative powers though? Won't there still be negative powers left over?

Comment: Not if $a_n=0$ for all $n<-k$.

Comment: Oh I see what you meant. Thankyou! I'll have to email the prof about the typo ..

Also what about the first part. Am I allowed to rearrange the terms like that?

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to do that whenever the series is absolutely convergent (and it is in this case).